# What is another way to say "have a wedding ceremony"?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-construction

If I want to inform a friend I'm getting married, could I use this sentence in the letter? What I'm trying to express is an alternative way to say *I'm getting married*.

> I'm writing to tell you I'm going to have a wedding ceremony soon.

Is there a more natural, alternative phrase?

Comment: Are you not sure about 'have' in (have a wedding ceremony)? Because there is no grammatical error in OP though It could be written bettre manner. Please highlight the part where you have a question?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. What's the better manner?

Comment: I would just say "I'm going to have a wedding in March" or "I'm going to get married in March"

Comment: I think what you wrote is fine. Keep in mind that marriage and a wedding ceremony are not the same thing, since some people get married but don't have a wedding ceremony.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write many things with a tone from formal to insouciant:

> A wonderful woman/man/fellow-canoeist has accepted my proposal. We are marrying each other on .... details.
>
> Our betrothal will end on  ...date... with our marriage at ...location...
>
> I'm so happy to announce our wedding plans ...details...
>
> My days of solitary sojourn through life in the world will happily end with my marriage to ...name... on ..date...
>
> Wedded bliss will be mine/ours following our ceremony  ...details...

Answer (score 3):

You can say anything you want, but that doesn't mean it'll be understood or appreciated.

Getting married is a traditional kind of thing, so why not use traditional language:

> [I'm getting married in the morning!](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/myfairlady/getmetothechurchontime.htm) Ding dong!
>   The bells are gonna chime. Pull out the stopper!
>   Let's have a whopper! But get me to the church on time!"

If you want to use a cliché, you can tell your friend that you're:

> "[gonna get hitched soon](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/get-hitched)".

Being "clever" isn't all it's cracked up to be.

Comment: *crack up* means "to become mentally ill" according to the dictionary. But I can't still resolve the puzzle in the last sentence.

Comment: @canoe: Sorry about using an old American idiom. Here's a [link that defines it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+it's+cracked+up+to+be). It just means that "it's not as good as people say it is".

Answer (score 1):

"I am going to have a wedding ceremony soon" is a grammatically correct statement, but it's just not what people normally say. It sounds like you are trying to emphasize the ceremony as opposed to the marriage or the wedding itself. If that's your point, I guess it could be valid, but it sounds very odd.

The conventional thing to say is, "I am getting married soon". Why do you not want to say that? It's hard for us to give good alternatives without knowing why you reject the "normal" phrasing.

Answer (score -1):

I would say:

> I'm writing to tell you I'm going to **get married** soon.

as that is the real(ly) long term plan.

The wedding ceremony, on the other hand is only for one day, so I would say it in two parts, like:

> I'm writing to tell you I'm going to **get married** soon. **The wedding ceremony will be...**"

Comment: *[to get married](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+married)* refers to the ceremony and/or legal act, not to the (long term) marriage.